# Why does Git automatically ignore most Node files?

Tags: node.js, git, twitter-bootstrap, npm, windows-8.1

I'm new at Node.js & NPM, and I'm experimenting by writing a website & adding it on Git (it's public, but only because I don't want to pay for private hosting). When I push the files to Github, Git automatically ignores pretty much every file related to Node, and I can't figure out why. Specifically, it seems to be ignoring all `node_modules` folders, `Gruntfile.js`es, and `package.json`s. Is this because of Git or Node, or is it a dummy move somewhere on my part?

When I do `git add -A`, `git add .` or `git add -u`, all of which are supposed to include all added & deleted files (I think), and then use `git commit` or `git commit -a` I get something like this:

```
$ git commit -m "hopefully added all files"
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.

Untracked files:
        .jshintrc
        app/
        libs/Gruntfile.js
        libs/node_modules/.bin/_mocha
        libs/node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd
        libs/node_modules/.bin/mocha
        etc.

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

I tried searching for `.gitignore` anywhere in the root folder, but all I could find was a `gitignore` file in my Bootstrap folder (speaking of, why is that there?), but if I'm correct, that shouldn't affect folders above it? It had rules for node_modules, but not Gruntfile.js or package.json, and when I commented all rules on it the files were still ignored.

This is a submodule, so it uses the `.git` folder of the parent project. That parent project has nothing but comments in its `.git/info/exclude`, and also has no `.gitignore`. No other submodules have a `.gitignore`, either.

So why is this happening?

EDIT: `git cherry` & `git diff` both show nothing. `git status` shows:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what wi

        libs/Gruntfile.js
        libs/node_modules/.bin/_mocha
        libs/node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd
        libs/node_modules/.bin/mocha
        libs/node_modules/.bin/mocha.cmd
        libs/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/
        etc.

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

EDIT 2: This website is a submodule, but I have never used `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` on the superproject or any other submodules. Nevertheless, could this have anything to do with the problem?

EDIT 3: As I said, `git add -A`, `git add .` & `git add -u` never add anything from node files or folders, but adding individual files & folders does. This makes it even weirder.

Comment: Anything in `.gitignore`?

Comment: I don't have a `.gitignore`, but as I said in my post, Bootstrap seems to have added one.

Comment: Are the untracked files listed there all the ones you intended to include?  The fact that they are showing there means git is not ignoring them via .gitignore, they just haven't been staged for commit.  `git add -A .` (don't forget the '.') should have done the trick. Can you try it again and then post the output of `git status`

Comment: Did you read my post? I answered all of the questions you just asked. I tried `git add -A` as well as `git add .` & `git add -u`. `git status` shows pretty much the same files as `git commit`, but I added the output to my post just in case.

Comment: If the files were ignored, be it through `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` or through the .git system settings themselves, they wouldn't be displayed at -all- in your status, even as `Untracked files`.  So, they certainly -aren't- ignored, and adding them will work just fine using `git add -A` or `git add <file>`, unless your install of git is corrupt.

Comment: So why are they untracked if I am using `git add -A`? Could it have something to do with having submodules (even though neither the supermodule nor any submodules have `.gitignore`s or `.git/info/exclude`s)?

Comment: I meant "untracked", or whatever they are. I'm not up with all the Git l1ng0. Does `git add -A` track everything, or do you need another command to do that?

Comment: are you doing the git add . in the submodule's directory, or in the parent directory (assuming you've done the submodule init dance)

Comment: I am doing git add in the root of the submodule's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have your project git repo that contains submodule repo in it. Can you please try this workflow?

1. In some folder clone your submodule-repo
2. In the same folder clone you project-repo and run
3. `cd project-repo`
4. `git submodule init`
5. `git submodule update`
6. `cd ../submodule-repo`
7. Make changes and `git commit -a; git push`
8. `cd ../project-repo/submoduleDir`
9. `git pull`

Now, you should have the parent repo pointing to the new submodule revision and when you cd to the project-repo you can commit this change (project-repo pointing to the latest submodule-repo revision).

More on this topic can be found here:
* http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
* http://joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Weirdest thing, when I deleted & recloned the repo awhile ago all the problems disappeared. I guess we'll never know what really happened. I suppose I'll accept your question because this is what I sorta did that fixed it. Thanks anyway.